# How to colourise some cell borders in R corrplot?

Tags: r, colors, border, correlation, r-corrplot

I would like to keep some cells in attention by making their borders clearly distinct from anything else.

The parameter `rect.col` is used to colorise all borders but I want to colorise only borders of the cells (3,3) and (7,7), for instance, by any halo color etc `heat.colors(100)` or `rainbow(12)`.

Code:

```
library("corrplot")
library("psych")

ids <- seq(1,11) 

M.cor <- cor(mtcars)
colnames(M.cor) <- ids
rownames(M.cor) <- ids

p.mat <- psych::corr.test(M.cor, adjust = "none", ci = F)
p.mat <- p.mat[["r"]]

corrplot(M.cor, 
  method = "color", 
  type = "upper", 
  tl.col = 'black', 
  diag = TRUE, 
  p.mat = p.mat, 
  sig.level = 0.0000005
)
```

Fig. 1 Output of the top code without cell bordering, 
Fig. 2 Output after manually converting all coordinates to upper triangle but artifact at (10,1),
Fig. 3 Output with window size fix

[image]
[image]
[image]

Input: locations by ids `(3,3)` and `(7,7)`
Expected output: two cells where borders marked on upper triangle

Pseudocode

```
# ids must be id.pairs  
# or just a list of two lists
createBorders <- function(id.pairs) {

  labbly(id.pairs,function(z){
    x <- z$V1
    y <- z$V2
    rect(x+0.5, y+0.5, x+1.5, y+1.5) # user20650

  })
}

corrplot(...)
# TODO Which datastructure to use there in the function as the paired list of ids? 
createBorders(ids.pairs)
```

### Testing user20650's proposal

```
rect(2+0.5, 9+0.5, 3+0.5, 10+0.5, border="white", lwd=2)
```

Output in Fig. 2. 
It would be great to have a function for this. 
Assume you have a list of IDs.

I think there is something wrong with the placement because (2,3),(9,10) leads to the point in (2,3),(2,3).

### Iterating user20650's Proposal in Chat

```
library("corrplot")
library("psych")

ids <- seq(1,11)

M.cor <- cor(mtcars)
colnames(M.cor) <- ids
rownames(M.cor) <- ids

p.mat <- psych::corr.test(M.cor, adjust = "none", ci = F)
p.mat <- p.mat[["r"]]

# Chat of http://stackoverflow.com/q/40538304/54964 user20650
cb <- function(corrPlot, ..., rectArgs = list() ){
        lst <- list(...)
                n <- ncol(corrPlot)
                nms <- colnames(corrPlot)
                colnames(corrPlot) <- if(is.null(nms)) 1:ncol(corrPlot) else nms

                xleft <- match(lst$x, colnames(corrPlot)) - 0.5
                ybottom <- n - match(lst$y, colnames(corrPlot)) + 0.5

                lst <- list(xleft=xleft, ybottom=ybottom, xright=xleft+1, ytop=ybottom+1)
                do.call(rect, c(lst, rectArgs))
}
plt <- corrplot(M.cor,
                method = "color",
                type = "upper",
                tl.col = 'black',
                diag = TRUE,
                p.mat = p.mat,
                sig.level = 0.0000005
               )
cb(plt, x=c(1, 3, 5), y=c(10, 7, 4), rectArgs=list(border="white", lwd=3))
```

Output where only one cell border marked in Fig. 3.

Expected output: three cell borders marked

### Restriction in Fig. 2 approach

You have to work all coordinates first to upper triangle. 
So you can now call only the following where output has an artifact at (10,1) in Fig. 2

```
cb(plt, x=c(10, 7, 5), y=c(1, 3, 4), rectArgs=list(border="white", lwd=3))
```

Expected output: no artifact at (10,1)

The cause of the artifact can be white background, but it occurs also if the border color is `red` so most probably it is not the cause. 
Solution - fix the window size and its output in Fig. 3

```
pdf("Rplots.pdf", height=10, width=10)
plt <- corrplot(M.cor,
                method = "color",
                type = "upper",
                tl.col = 'black',
                diag = TRUE,
                p.mat = p.mat,
                sig.level = 0.0000005
               )
cb(plt, x=c(10, 7, 5), y=c(1, 3, 4), rectArgs=list(border="red", lwd=3))
dev.off()
```

R: 3.3.1
OS: Debian 8.5
Docs corrplot: [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/corrplot.pdf)

Comment: I think you will likely have to do this manually ie `rect(2+0.5, 9+0.5, 3+0.5, 10+0.5, border="white", lwd=2)` . Of course, if you know the number of cells, upper / lower triangle , other setting you could automate this

Comment: this is a rough start ; see if you can make something work for you http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127905/masi-qa

Comment: @user20650 Please, see the wiki answer below. There are still some pseudocodes which I cannot do but I know what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal where still pseudocode `mark.ids`. I found best to have `plt` and `mark.ids` as the options of `corrplotCellBorders` which creates corrplot with bordered wanted cells

```
mark.ids <- {x <- c(1), y <- c(2)} # TODO pseudocode
corrplotCellBorders(plt, mark.ids)
cb(plt, x, y, rectArgs=list(border="red", lwd=3))

# Chat of https://stackoverflow.com/q/40538304/54964 user20650
# createBorders.r, test.createBorders. 
cb <- function(corrPlot, ..., rectArgs = list() ){ 
# ... pass named vector of x and y names 
# for upper x > y, lower x < y 
  lst <- list(...) 

  n <- ncol(corrPlot) 
  nms <- colnames(corrPlot) 
  colnames(corrPlot) <- if(is.null(nms)) 1:ncol(corrPlot) else nms 

  xleft <- match(lst$x, colnames(corrPlot)) - 0.5 
  ybottom <- n - match(lst$y, colnames(corrPlot)) + 0.5 

  lst <- list(xleft=xleft, ybottom=ybottom, xright=xleft+1, ytop=ybottom+1) 
  do.call(rect, c(lst, rectArgs)) 
}

corrplotCellBorders <- function(plt, mark.ids) {
  x <- mark.ids$x
  y <- mark.ids$y
  cb(plt, x, y, rectArgs=list(border="red", lwd=3))
}
```

Open

- How to create `mark.ids` such that you can call its items by `mark.ids$x` and `mark.ids$y`?
- Integrate point order neutrality for the upper triangle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40552276/54964)