# How to flip pairs into X>Y order in R?

Tags: r, data-structures

The user gives pairs of ids which corresponds to ids in the upper triangle that is when Y > X. 
I am thinking how you should handle the points and which data structure is best here. 
I think having pairs like `(x1,y1), (y3,x3), ...` is intuitive but better can be `c(x1,x2,x3,...), c(y1,y2,y3, ...)` but then it is only about the flipping problem. 
Example inputs

1. (10,1), (7,3), (5,4) - returns the same
2. (1,10), (7,3), (5,4) - returns (10,1), (7,3), (5,4)
3. (1,10), (7,3), (4,5) - returns (10,1), (7,3), (5,4)

Pseudocode where I am still not sure about the data structure in `id.pairs` or shoul

```
  lapply(id.pairs,function(z){
    x <- z$V1
    y <- z$V2
    ...
  })

 # not sure if possible
 lapply({x.points, y.points}, function(z){
    x <- z$V1
    y <- z$V2
    ...
  })
```

Motivation: to give correct points for the following function in the upper triangle

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/q/40538304/54964
cb(plt, x=c(10, 7, 5), y=c(1, 3, 4), rectArgs=list(border="red", lwd=3))
```

### Testing MarkPeterson's [proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40552276/54964)

I think his first method can work but I am thinking how to apply his `lapply` to the parameters `xleft` and `ybottom`

```
# Complete test code http://paste.ubuntu.com/23461804/
# Chat of https://stackoverflow.com/q/40538304/54964 user20650
cb <- function(corrPlot, ..., rectArgs = list() ){ 
                lst <- list(...) 
                lapply({x,y}, function(x){
                  c(max(x), min(x))
                })

                xleft <- match(lst$x, colnames(corrPlot)) - 0.5
                ybottom <- n - match(lst$y, colnames(corrPlot)) + 0.5
}
```

R: 3.3.1
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: Is `labbly` really a thing or is it a typo?

Comment: Thank you! Feel free to edit such mistakes next time directly yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume a list of paired points, and that you can trust the values are valid (probably not a fair assumption, but defenses could be added), it seems that you may be able to just do this with `min` and `max`:

```
inputData <-
  list(
    c(1,10)
    , c(7,3)
    , c(4,5)
  )

lapply(inputData, function(x){
  c(max(x), min(x))
})
```

gives

```
[[1]]
[1] 10  1

[[2]]
[1] 7 3

[[3]]
[1] 5 4
```

You can get the same basic output from vectors, if you convert to a matrix/data.frame, then use `apply` by row with the same function. The matrix approach likely looks something like:

```
matData <-
  do.call(rbind, inputData)

t(apply(matData, 1, function(x){
  c(max(x), min(x))
}))
```

and gives:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   10    1
[2,]    7    3
[3,]    5    4
```

Given the update, I have to say that I agree with @Frank that you should take the basic idea of what I have here, but use `pmax` and `pmin` instead. The function then looks like this (note, I am setting `x` and `y` as arguments, since they appear to be required).

```
cb <- function(corrPlot, x, y, rectArgs = list() ){ 
  # ... pass named vector of x and y names 
  # for upper x > y, lower x < y 
  useX <- pmax(x, y)
  useY <- pmin(x,y)

  n <- ncol(corrPlot)
  nms <- colnames(corrPlot)
  colnames(corrPlot) <- if(is.null(nms)) 1:ncol(corrPlot) else nms

  xleft <- match(useX, colnames(corrPlot)) - 0.5
  ybottom <- n - match(useY, colnames(corrPlot)) + 0.5

  lst <- list(xleft=xleft, ybottom=ybottom, xright=xleft+1, ytop=ybottom+1) 
  do.call(rect, c(lst, rectArgs))
}
```

Then, this appears to work as expected:

```
cb(plt, x=c(1, 3, 4), y=c(10, 7, 5), rectArgs=list(border="red", lwd=3))
```

As expected, there are three ways to generate the desired pair ordering, depending on whether they come in a list of pairs, a matrix/data.frame, or a vector. The alternative approach would be to accept either a list or a matrix/data.frame as an argument to the function, then use the `lapply` or `apply` functions above and extract your required values from those.

Comment: For the case of two vectors, x and y, the flipping could be more efficient `cbind(pmax(x,y), pmin(x,y))` rather than `apply`, I guess.

Comment: This is the scope http://paste.ubuntu.com/23461804/ I think your `lapply` can be added in `cb`. There is `lst$x` and `lst$y` which should be separately processed by your method. Can it be done? - - I am thinking how to pass the information from `c(max(x), min(x))` there.