# How to draw line around significant values in R's corrplot package

Tags: r, graphics, r-corrplot

I have been asked to obtain a correlation plot for a colaborator.
My choice is to use R for the task, specifically the **corrplot** package.
I have been researching on the internet and [I found multiple ways to obtain such graphics](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/correlation-matrix-a-quick-start-guide-to-analyze-format-and-visualize-a-correlation-matrix-using-r-software), but not the specific graphic I was asked for (as you can see in the picture the significant values are highlighted by drawing a square around the significant tile), which is puzzling me.

[Example of the correlation plot required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rthe.jpg)

The closest result I achieve is using the code under this lines, but I do not seem to be able to find the option to draw line around the significant tiles (if exists).

```
#Insignificant correlations are leaved blank
corrplot(res3$r, type="upper", order="hclust", 
         p.mat = res3$P, sig.level = 0.01, insig = "blank")
```

I tried adding the "addrect" parameter but it didn't work.

```
#Insignificant correlation are crossed
corrplot(res3$r, type="upper", order="hclust", p.mat = res3$P,
         addrect=2, sig.level = 0.01, insig = "blank")
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you could find which cells are to have the border changed by inspection of the pvalue matrix, and then apply this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538304/how-to-colourise-some-cell-borders-in-r-corrplot (ps addrect is related to clustering)

Comment: Thank you for your answer user20650

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`corrplot` allows you to add new plots to an already existing one. Therefore, once you've created the plot of the initial correlation matrix, you can simply add those cells that you want to highlight in an iterative manner using `corrplot(..., add = TRUE)`.

The only thing required to achieve your goal is an indices vecor (which I called 'ids') to tell R which cells to highlight. Note that for reasons of simplicity, I took a random `sample` of the initial correlation matrix, but things like `ids <- which(p.value < 0.01)` (assuming that you've stored your significance levels in a separate vector) would work similarly.

```
library(corrplot)

## create and visualize correlation matrix
data(mtcars)
M <- cor(mtcars)

corrplot(M, cl.pos = "n", na.label = " ")

## select cells to highlight (e.g., statistically significant values)
set.seed(10)
ids <- sample(1:length(M), 15L)

## duplicate correlation matrix and reject all irrelevant values
N <- M
N[-ids] <- NA

## add significant cells to the initial corrplot iteratively 
for (i in ids) {
  O <- N
  O[-i] <- NA
  corrplot(O, cl.pos = "n", na.label = " ", addgrid.col = "black", add = TRUE, 
           bg = "transparent", tl.col = "transparent")
}
```

[image: corrplot]

Note that you could also add all values to highlight in one go (i.e., without requiring a `for` loop) using `corrplot(N, ...)`, but in that case, an undesirable black margin is drawn all around the plotting area.